# pgfplot Memory Problem

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-external, shell-escape, groupplots

I am plotting  `groupplots` like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309039/graph-with-multiple-y-axes/309111#309111)

The data set is quite large (15000 data points for each plot and each group has 5 such plots). When Latex threw memory shortage error, I tried using externalization of tikz. But when I compile `pdflatex -shell-escape <filename>` from Command line, I get the following error

```
! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-e
rror -interaction=batchmode -jobname "Second_phase_updates-figure5" "\def\tikze
xternalrealjob{Second_phase_updates}\input{Second_phase_updates}"' did NOT resu
lt in a usable output file 'Second_phase_updates-figure5' (expected one of .pdf
:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). Please verify that you have enabled system calls. For pdfla
tex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-escape'. Sometimes it is also named 'write 18' or
 something like that. Or maybe the command simply failed? Error messages can be
 found in 'Second_phase_updates-figure5.log'. If you continue now, I'll try to 
typeset the picture.
See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
l.265 \end{tikzpicture}
?
```

Help me sort this error.
It is not a duplicate of anything. I have tried all possible suggested solutions before posting this.

Here I include a MWE.

```
     \documentclass{standalone}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepackage{pgfplotstable}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{external} 
    \tikzexternalize
    \tikzset{external/force remake}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}[
     group style={
      group size=1 by 2,  % sets number of columns and rows in groupplot array
      vertical sep=0pt,   % vertical distance between axes
     },
     axis y line=left, % y axis line on left side only
     xmin=0,xmax=1000,   % set axis
     ymin=0,           % limits
     domain=1:9,       % domain, just for example
     width=15cm,       % width
     height=5cm,       % and height for each axis
     scale only axis,  % disregard labels and ticks for scaling
     no markers, 
     enlarge y limits=upper,
    ]

    \nextgroupplot[
        ylabel=$SPL(dB)$,
        ylabel style={at={(rel axis cs:0,1)},above,rotate=-90}, %move ylabel a bit
        axis x line=none] % remove x-axis lines
     \addplot table [y=p5, x=frequency]{1m_f2800.txt};

\nextgroupplot[axis x line=none]
 \addplot [y=p4, x=frequency]{1m_f2800.txt};
\nextgroupplot[axis x line=none]
 \addplot [y=p3, x=frequency]{1m_f2800.txt};
\nextgroupplot[axis x line=none]
 \addplot [y=p2, x=frequency]{1m_f2800.txt};


    \nextgroupplot[
        axis x line=bottom, % only x axis line at bottom
        xlabel=$Frequency$,
        %xlabel style={at={(rel axis cs:1,0)},right}]
     \addplot table [y=p1, x=frequency]{1m_f2800.txt}; 

    \end{groupplot}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}

    \end{document}
```

The data file can be found [here](http://www.wikiupload.com/D1KU1SRT9JZLXWB)

Comment: Are you sure this is the actual error and not that pdflatex runs out of memory because of the large number of data items?

Comment: @daleif It did ran out of memory. So I used externalization(I assume that this should sort out the memory problem). Then when I compile it in Command line, it throws the above error.

Comment: I'm quite sure what the externalization does but I'm quite sure it does not solve the memory problem. Are you sure you actually need 6000 data points for each plot? You might be able to compile it with luatatex

Comment: @daleif In that case can you tell me how do I expand Tex maker memory? How do I compile with Luatatex?

Comment: It might not be worth messing with the memory, there are many other questions about that in this site. Regarding lualatex, if you are currently using pdflatex what would you guess would be the command used to call lualatex (despite the name it outputs pdf, but it has dynamic memory allocation)

Comment: @daleif I get the same error for lualatex

Comment: Then we are out of luck. Unless you provide a minimal example that we can run on our own systems we cannot help (have you tried lualatex and no externalization?

Comment: @daleif I have included a MWE and the data file in the updated edit

Comment: Not at a computer so I can not test it, hopefully someone else picks it up (you might want to change question title to something more relevant)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tikz externalization can't solve memory problems, because what it does is saving the output of the tikzpicture environments as an external file (pdf or eps), after it has been compiled. If your code doesn't compile, nothing can be externalized.

After correction of your syntax errors (read your error messages!) it compiles for me with LuaLatex. But you should also check your groupplot commands, this gives additional warning messages. You're just defining a matrix of 1x2, but adding a lot more plots than just two!

[image]

**Code**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{groupplot}[
                          group style={
                          group size=1 by 5,  % sets number of columns and rows in groupplot array
                          vertical sep=10pt,   % vertical distance between axes
                          },
                          axis y line=left, % y axis line on left side only
                          xmin=0,xmax=1000,   % set axis
                          ymin=0,           % limits
                          domain=1:9,       % domain, just for example
                          width=15cm,       % width
                          height=5cm,       % and height for each axis
                          scale only axis,  % disregard labels and ticks for scaling
                          no markers, 
                          enlarge y limits=upper,
                        ]
        %
        \nextgroupplot[
                        ylabel=$SPL$ (dB),
                        ylabel style={at={(rel axis cs:0,1)},above,rotate=-90}, %move ylabel a bit
                        axis x line=none % remove x-axis lines
                      ] 
        \addplot table [y=p5, x=frequency]{1m_f2800.txt};
        %
        \nextgroupplot[axis x line=none]
        \addplot table [y=p4, x=frequency]{1m_f2800.txt};
        %
        \nextgroupplot[axis x line=none]
        \addplot table [y=p3, x=frequency]{1m_f2800.txt};
        %
        \nextgroupplot[axis x line=none]
        \addplot table [y=p2, x=frequency]{1m_f2800.txt};
        %
        \nextgroupplot[
                        axis x line=bottom, % only x axis line at bottom
                        xlabel=Frequency,
                        %xlabel style={at={(rel axis cs:1,0)},right}
                      ]
        \addplot table [y=p1, x=frequency]{1m_f2800.txt}; 
        %
        \end{groupplot}
        %
    \end{tikzpicture}
    %
\end{document}
```

Comment: My bad! I compile it correctly in my machine but made a mistake in MWE. The actual problem was that luatexbase.sty was missing, I fixed it. Thanks :)