# Spy glasses in a group plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, groupplots, spy

I have a group plot in which the graphs have common x axis and are stacked one over the other- like the one given[here.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309039/graph-with-multiple-y-axes)

Now, I want to have a spy glass on each of these plots in the group.
But when I include a spy glass in the group plot, the spy glass is plotted only on the last plot in the group. See the picture below
[image]
The different circles you see in the last plot in the group are spy glasses of different size I have used for each plot, but all ended up in the last plot. How do I rectify this?
Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[spy using outlines={circle, magnification=1.75, connect spies}]
\begin{groupplot}[
 group style={
  group size=1 by 4,  % sets number of columns and rows in groupplot array
  vertical sep=0pt,   % vertical distance between axes
 },
 axis y line=left, % y axis line on left side only
 xmin=0,xmax=10,   % set axis
 ymin=0,           % limits
 domain=1:9,       % domain, just for example
 width=10cm,       % width
 height=3cm,       % and height for each axis
 scale only axis,  % disregard labels and ticks for scaling
 no markers, 
 enlarge y limits=upper,
]

\nextgroupplot[
    ylabel=$y$,
    ylabel style={at={(rel axis cs:0,1)},above,rotate=-90}, %move ylabel a bit
    axis x line=none] % remove x-axis lines
 \addplot{x};
 \coordinate (spypoint) at (axis cs:5,0.85);
        \coordinate (magnifyglass) at (axis cs:7.5,1.3);
        \spy [blue, size=2.5cm] on (spypoint) in node[fill=white] at (magnifyglass);

\nextgroupplot[axis x line=none]
 \addplot{-x + 10}; 
 \coordinate (spypoint) at (axis cs:5,0.85);
        \coordinate (magnifyglass) at (axis cs:7.5,1.30);
        \spy [blue, size=3.0cm] on (spypoint) in node[fill=white] at (magnifyglass);

\nextgroupplot[axis x line=none]
 \addplot{x*x}; 
 \coordinate (spypoint) at (axis cs:5,0.85);
        \coordinate (magnifyglass) at (axis cs:7.5,1.30);
        \spy [blue, size=3.5cm] on (spypoint) in node[fill=white] at (magnifyglass);

\nextgroupplot[
    axis x line=bottom, % only x axis line at bottom
    xlabel=$x$,
    xlabel style={at={(rel axis cs:1,0)},right}]
 \addplot+[samples=200] {abs(sin(x*180/pi))}; 
 \coordinate (spypoint) at (axis cs:5,0.85);
        \coordinate (magnifyglass) at (axis cs:7.5,1.30);
        \spy [blue, size=1.5cm] on (spypoint) in node[fill=white] at (magnifyglass);

\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Someone please shed some light on this.

Comment: Why using groupplots? I don't think it's the most appropriate choice here.

Comment: @Alenanno The graph given here is for representation purpose only. It is an example as in "Minimum working example" . I have a huuuuge data set which exactly requires this kind of format of plot.

Comment: Try to use different names for each couple of coordinates: `spypoint1` and `magnifyglass1`, then `spypoint2` and `magnifyglass1`, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use different names for each couple of coordinates: `spypoint1` and `magnifyglass1`, then `spypoint2` and `magnifyglass2`, etc.

Result:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[spy using outlines={circle, magnification=1.75, connect spies}]
\begin{groupplot}[
 group style={
  group size=1 by 4,  % sets number of columns and rows in groupplot array
  vertical sep=0pt,   % vertical distance between axes
 },
 axis y line=left, % y axis line on left side only
 xmin=0,xmax=10,   % set axis
 ymin=0,           % limits
 domain=1:9,       % domain, just for example
 width=10cm,       % width
 height=3cm,       % and height for each axis
 scale only axis,  % disregard labels and ticks for scaling
 no markers, 
 enlarge y limits=upper,
]

\nextgroupplot[
    ylabel=$y$,
    ylabel style={at={(rel axis cs:0,1)},above,rotate=-90}, %move ylabel a bit
    axis x line=none] % remove x-axis lines
 \addplot{x};
 \coordinate (spypoint1) at (axis cs:5,0.85);
        \coordinate (magnifyglass1) at (axis cs:7.5,1.3);
        \spy [blue, size=2.5cm] on (spypoint1) in node[fill=white] at (magnifyglass1);

\nextgroupplot[axis x line=none]
 \addplot{-x + 10}; 
 \coordinate (spypoint2) at (axis cs:5,0.85);
        \coordinate (magnifyglass2) at (axis cs:7.5,1.30);
        \spy [orange, size=3.0cm] on (spypoint2) in node[fill=white] at (magnifyglass2);

\nextgroupplot[axis x line=none]
 \addplot{x*x}; 
 \coordinate (spypoint3) at (axis cs:5,0.85);
        \coordinate (magnifyglass3) at (axis cs:7.5,1.30);
        \spy [green, size=3.5cm] on (spypoint3) in node[fill=white] at (magnifyglass3);

\nextgroupplot[
    axis x line=bottom, % only x axis line at bottom
    xlabel=$x$,
    xlabel style={at={(rel axis cs:1,0)},right}]
 \addplot+[samples=200] {abs(sin(x*180/pi))}; 
 \coordinate (spypoint4) at (axis cs:5,0.85);
        \coordinate (magnifyglass4) at (axis cs:7.5,1.30);
        \spy [violet, size=1.5cm] on (spypoint4) in node[fill=white] at (magnifyglass4);

\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]